# How to set up an SSL certificate for Express v4.13?

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https

Every answer I can find only talks about old versions of express.js, where there existed a method called "createServer". Now that it no longer exists, I have no idea how to add my SSL certificate to my Node.js server. All I know is I have my .pem key and my .pem cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [https.createServer](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) constructor on the builtin nodejs `https` module. It takes as first parameter the same options used by tls.createServer and you can use your express app as second parameter.

Comment: Nodejs https module API is stable. You can find the documentation of the latest version [here](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) and `createServer` is not deprecated.

Comment: What it is deprecated is the `createServer` method of express applications and not the function on the built in module of Nodejs